# Bootstrap table style not applying to JS generated table

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello I am new to website development (started a couple of days ago).

I have some programming experience using Python and C#.

I have been trying to generate an HTML table using JS and apply it a Bootstrap css style.

I can't seem to get it to work.

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

I hope to get something that styles like this (simplified from: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_basic&stacked=h))

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Basic Table</h2>
      <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
      <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

My html page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSVParser</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/csvToHtml.js"></script>
        <form onsubmit="return processFile();" action="#" name="myForm" id="aForm" method="POST">
            <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submitMe" value="Process File">
        </form>

        <table id="myTable" class="table"></table>
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

and the JS script is:

```
function processFile() {
 var fileSize = 0;
 var theFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
 if (theFile) {
     var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
     var headerLine = "";
     var myReader = new FileReader();
     myReader.onload = function(e) {
         var content = myReader.result;
         var lines = content.split("\r");
         for (var count = 0; count < lines.length; count++) {
             var row = document.createElement("tr");
             var rowContent = lines[count].split(",");
             for (var i = 0; i < rowContent.length; i++) {
                 if (count == 0) {
                     var cellElement = document.createElement("th");
                 } else {
                     var cellElement = document.createElement("td");
                 }
                 var cellContent = document.createTextNode(rowContent[i]);
                 cellElement.appendChild(cellContent);
                 row.appendChild(cellElement);
             }
             myTable.appendChild(row);
        }
    }
    myReader.readAsText(theFile);
 }
 return false;
}
```

The csv data file I load looks like this:

```
TestA,TestB,TestC,TestD
Alpha,0.551608445,0.807554763,54.8608682
Beta,0.191220409,0.279946678,57.55254144
```

This is the generated HTML table from the JS:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>TestA</th>
        <th>TestB</th>
        <th>TestC</th>
        <th>TestD</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alpha</td>
        <td>0.551608445</td>
        <td>0.807554763</td>
        <td>54.8608682</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Beta</td>
        <td>0.191220409</td>
        <td>0.279946678</td>
        <td>57.55254144</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can we see the generated HTML for the table?

Comment: Hi VTodorov, I have tried to use console.log() but without success. I don't know how I could get it to show.

Comment: You could use the browsers "elements" tab (for chrome). Rightclick on the page and click "View page source".

Comment: That worked, I added the generated table at the end of the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a `<tbody>` element around all the `<tr>` Elements. thats it. if you insert this additionally you are fine with your layout.

---

I've changed your code quite a bit but here is a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSVParser</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="#" name="myForm" id="aForm" method="POST">
                <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"><br>
                <input type="button" name="submitMe" value="Process File" onclick="processFile();">
            </form>
            <table id="myTable" class="table"></table>
        </div>
        
        </body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function processFile() {
                 var fileSize = 0;
                 var theFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
                 if (theFile) {
                     var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                     var headerLine = "";
                     var myReader = new FileReader();
                     myReader.onload = function(e) {
                         var content = myReader.result;
                         var lines = content.split("\r");
                         var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

                         for (var count = 0; count < lines.length; count++) {
                             var row = document.createElement("tr");
                             var rowContent = lines[count].split(",");
                             for (var i = 0; i < rowContent.length; i++) {
                                 if (count == 0) {
                                     var cellElement = document.createElement("th");
                                 } else {
                                     var cellElement = document.createElement("td");
                                 }
                                 var cellContent = document.createTextNode(rowContent[i]);
                                 cellElement.appendChild(cellContent);
                                 row.appendChild(cellElement);
                             }
                             tbody.appendChild(row);
                        }

                        table.appendChild(tbody);
                    }
                    myReader.readAsText(theFile);
                 }

                 return false;
            }
        </script>
</html>
```

---

**Working example without having to upload a file**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSVParser</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="#" name="myForm" id="aForm" method="POST">
                <textarea id="myFile" name="myFile">TestA,TestB,TestC,TestD
Alpha,0.551608445,0.807554763,54.8608682
Beta,0.191220409,0.279946678,57.55254144</textarea><br>
                <input type="button" name="submitMe" value="Process File" onclick="processFile();">
            </form>
            <table id="myTable" class="table"></table>
        </div>
        
        </body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function processFile() {
                var table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
                var content = $("#myFile").val();
                var lines = content.split("\n");
                var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

                for (var count = 0; count < lines.length; count++) {
                    var row = document.createElement("tr");
                    var rowContent = lines[count].split(",");

                    for (var i = 0; i < rowContent.length; i++) {
                        if (count == 0) {
                            var cellElement = document.createElement("th");
                        } else {
                            var cellElement = document.createElement("td");
                        }

                        var cellContent = document.createTextNode(rowContent[i]);
                        cellElement.appendChild(cellContent);
                        row.appendChild(cellElement);
                    }

                    tbody.appendChild(row);
                }

                table.appendChild(tbody);

                return false;
            }
        </script>
</html>
```

---

**ALSO!** You are using `myTable.appendChild(row);` in your code although you've never initialized any `myTable` variable.

Comment: Could you share your definition of *"working example"* with us, please? You're right about the `<tbody>` element, but your example doesn't work for me.

Comment: I guess you didnt upload a csv file as given by @Sorade

Comment: `content="TestA,TestB,TestC,TestD\rAlpha,0.551608445,0.807554763,54.8608682\rBeta,0.191220409,0.279946678,57.55254144"`. We're not testing the file upload here, are we? My point being: I shouldn't have to create files on my computer in order to answer or test answers on [so]. That's the whole point of snippets. Not having to do anything locally.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I've updated my answer regarding your criticisms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and apologies for not uploading the csv data. I copy pasted the data, but knowing that using a textarea would result in the same thing as a csv file wasn't obvious for me.

Comment: @Sorade be aware that i changed the new-line symbol from `\r` to `\n`

Answer (score -1):

Load your js script just before the `</body>` end tag.
Now you are loading the JavaScript before the browser has read all your tags and by then it can't find the elements you are querying in your script.

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
  
  <form onsubmit="return processFile();" action="#" name="myForm" id="aForm" method="POST">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submitMe" value="Process File">
  </form>

  <table id="myTable" class="table"></table>
  </div>
  <!-- Here's the difference -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/csvToHtml.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Comment: By end tag do you mean the last html, body or div ? Could you copy paste and amend the code in your reply ?? That would be greate !

Comment: Sorry I meant the body end tag. I think my tag got lost in the wiki syntax.